# How to test if Node.js app is able to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, initialization

I'm trying to add a test to check if Node.js app is starting. for example it might crash after running `npm start`. and I want to verify it's able to start.

I tried searching the web for such ways to tests but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: do you mean a unit test ?

Comment: If this could be done via a unit-test then it's great. but it's not exactly a scneario for unit-test since i'm not testing a specific function instead I want to test if `npm start` fails.

Answer (score 0):

In a production environment you can either use a very popular NPM module named "[PM2(Process Manager 2)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)" or containerize your entire application and then let Docker handle the application's life-cycle

---

How to start an Node app under PM2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2#start-an-application

Docker with "always" restart policy: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically

Comment: how is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is an HTTP(S) server, then you might want to add it a dummy entry point, something like `/hello` which returns 200 (OK). This way you could run a command line HTTP client, such as `curl`, and see if it successfully gets the expected response.

However, this is not a unit test, it's an integration test.

Note also, that this test should be run as a separate process.

Comment: What if I want to test this before deploying?

Comment: @asker asky, I'm not sure what your scenario is. Perhaps you could add more details to your question?